# How do I force vscode to recognise my .d.ts files over the default ones?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, visual-studio-code

So as the title says I have a project with type declaration files, one of the declares is a File object and new File() class (also a function, long story). Issue is VsCode seems insistent on using the default File object instead of my custom one. 
How do I force it to use mine over the default one?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does your project use any dom typings? If not, you could just exclude those so that your `File` class is always used

Comment: No I don't believe it does, that could work thanks!